# KeyGenerator for C# project

Tags: c#, key, generator

Hi all there are two classes There is a button on it all handled. How to create key generator for my project? Thanks for any information.

## SymCryptography class

```
namespace MyProject
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    using System.Text;

    public class SymCryptography
    {
        private ServiceProviderEnum mAlgorithm;
        private SymmetricAlgorithm mCryptoService;
        private string mKey;
        private string mSalt;

        public SymCryptography()
        {
            this.mKey = string.Empty;
            this.mSalt = string.Empty;
            this.mCryptoService = new RijndaelManaged();
            this.mCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.Rijndael;
        }

        public SymCryptography(ServiceProviderEnum serviceProvider)
        {
            this.mKey = string.Empty;
            this.mSalt = string.Empty;
            switch (serviceProvider)
            {
                case ServiceProviderEnum.Rijndael:
                    this.mCryptoService = new RijndaelManaged();
                    this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.Rijndael;
                    break;

                case ServiceProviderEnum.RC2:
                    this.mCryptoService = new RC2CryptoServiceProvider();
                    this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.RC2;
                    break;

                case ServiceProviderEnum.DES:
                    this.mCryptoService = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
                    this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.DES;
                    break;

                case ServiceProviderEnum.TripleDES:
                    this.mCryptoService = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
                    this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.TripleDES;
                    break;
            }
            this.mCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        }

        public SymCryptography(string serviceProviderName)
        {
            this.mKey = string.Empty;
            this.mSalt = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string str = serviceProviderName.ToLower();
                if (str != null)
                {
                    if (str != "rijndael")
                    {
                        if (str == "rc2")
                        {
                            goto Label_006F;
                        }
                        if (str == "des")
                        {
                            goto Label_007F;
                        }
                        if (str == "tripledes")
                        {
                            goto Label_008F;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serviceProviderName = "Rijndael";
                        this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.Rijndael;
                    }
                }
                goto Label_009F;
            Label_006F:
                serviceProviderName = "RC2";
                this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.RC2;
                goto Label_009F;
            Label_007F:
                serviceProviderName = "DES";
                this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.DES;
                goto Label_009F;
            Label_008F:
                serviceProviderName = "TripleDES";
                this.mAlgorithm = ServiceProviderEnum.TripleDES;
            Label_009F:
                this.mCryptoService = (SymmetricAlgorithm) CryptoConfig.CreateFromName(serviceProviderName);
                this.mCryptoService.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        public virtual string Decrypt(string cryptoText)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(cryptoText);
            byte[] legalKey = this.GetLegalKey();
            this.mCryptoService.Key = legalKey;
            this.SetLegalIV();
            ICryptoTransform transform = this.mCryptoService.CreateDecryptor();
            try
            {
                MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream2);
                return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public virtual string Encrypt(string plainText)
        {
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText);
            byte[] legalKey = this.GetLegalKey();
            this.mCryptoService.Key = legalKey;
            this.SetLegalIV();
            ICryptoTransform transform = this.mCryptoService.CreateEncryptor();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            CryptoStream stream2 = new CryptoStream(stream, transform, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
            stream2.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream2.FlushFinalBlock();
            byte[] inArray = stream.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray, 0, inArray.GetLength(0));
        }

        public virtual byte[] GetLegalKey()
        {
            if (this.mCryptoService.LegalKeySizes.Length > 0)
            {
                int num = this.mKey.Length * 8;
                int minSize = this.mCryptoService.LegalKeySizes[0].MinSize;
                int maxSize = this.mCryptoService.LegalKeySizes[0].MaxSize;
                int skipSize = this.mCryptoService.LegalKeySizes[0].SkipSize;
                if (num > maxSize)
                {
                    this.mKey = this.mKey.Substring(0, maxSize / 8);
                }
                else if (num < maxSize)
                {
                    int num5 = (num <= minSize) ? minSize : ((num - (num % skipSize)) + skipSize);
                    if (num < num5)
                    {
                        this.mKey = this.mKey.PadRight(num5 / 8, '*');
                    }
                }
            }
            PasswordDeriveBytes bytes = new PasswordDeriveBytes(this.mKey, Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(this.mSalt));
            return bytes.GetBytes(this.mKey.Length);
        }

        private void SetLegalIV()
        {
            if (this.mAlgorithm == ServiceProviderEnum.Rijndael)
            {
                this.mCryptoService.IV = new byte[] { 15, 0x6f, 0x13, 0x2e, 0x35, 0xc2, 0xcd, 0xf9, 5, 70, 0x9c, 0xea, 0xa8, 0x4b, 0x73, 0xcc };
            }
            else
            {
                this.mCryptoService.IV = new byte[] { 15, 0x6f, 0x13, 0x2e, 0x35, 0xc2, 0xcd, 0xf9 };
            }
        }

        public string Key
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mKey;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mKey = value;
            }
        }

        public string Salt
        {
            get
            {
                return this.mSalt;
            }
            set
            {
                this.mSalt = value;
            }
        }

        public enum ServiceProviderEnum
        {
            Rijndael,
            RC2,
            DES,
            TripleDES
        }
    }
}


CSecurity class
===============


  namespace MyProject
    {
        using System;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Web.Security;
        using System.Windows.Forms;

        public class CSecurity
        {
            public bool CheckKeys(string UserName, string Company, string ProductKey)
            {
                string st = UserName + this.GetVolumeSerial(Path.GetPathRoot(Application.ExecutablePath)) + Environment.ProcessorCount.ToString() + Company;
                string str2 = "";
                string cryptoText = "-";
                if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\key.gpg"))
                {
                    cryptoText = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + @"\key.gpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                string str4 = new SymCryptography { Key = "fr#$@^^%HJBUYTHAEHJFTRDChjbksfdue37B33&%$#" }.Decrypt(cryptoText);
                string str5 = "^*hdeZEsw5";
                for (int i = 0; i < str4.Length; i++)
                {
                    str2 = str2 + char.ConvertFromUtf32(Convert.ToInt32(str4[i]) ^ Convert.ToInt32(str5[i]));
                }
                DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
                try
                {
                    now = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(str2.Split(new char[] { '-' })[0]), Convert.ToInt32(str2.Split(new char[] { '-' })[1]), Convert.ToInt32(str2.Split(new char[] { '-' })[2]));
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return ((this.GetMD5(st) == ProductKey) && (DateTime.Now < now));

            }

            private string GetMD5(string st)
            {
                return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(st, "md5");
            }

            public string GetUserKey()
            {
                return (this.GetVolumeSerial(Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.CurrentDirectory)) + Environment.ProcessorCount.ToString());
            }

            [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern long GetVolumeInformation(string PathName, StringBuilder VolumeNameBuffer, uint VolumeNameSize, ref uint VolumeSerialNumber, ref uint MaximumComponentLength, ref uint FileSystemFlags, StringBuilder FileSystemNameBuffer, uint FileSystemNameSize);
            private string GetVolumeSerial(string strDriveLetter)
            {
                uint volumeSerialNumber = 0;
                uint maximumComponentLength = 0;
                StringBuilder volumeNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(0x100);
                uint fileSystemFlags = 0;
                StringBuilder fileSystemNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(0x100);
                long num4 = GetVolumeInformation(strDriveLetter, volumeNameBuffer, (uint) volumeNameBuffer.Capacity, ref volumeSerialNumber, ref maximumComponentLength, ref fileSystemFlags, fileSystemNameBuffer, (uint) fileSystemNameBuffer.Capacity);
                return Convert.ToString(volumeSerialNumber);
            }

            public bool isRegistered()
            {
                string[] strArray;
                if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + @"\reg.gpg"))
                {
                    strArray = File.ReadAllLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\reg.gpg");
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
                if (strArray.Length < 3)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                string userName = "-";
                userName = strArray[0];
                string company = "-";
                company = strArray[1];
                string str3 = "-";
                str3 = strArray[2];
                if (((userName == null) || (company == null)) || (str3 == null))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return this.CheckKeys(userName, company, str3.Replace("-", ""));
            }

            public void WriteRegInfo(string UserName, string Company, string ProductKey)
            {
                string[] contents = new string[] { UserName, Company, ProductKey };
                File.WriteAllLines(Application.StartupPath + @"\reg.gpg", contents);
            }
        }
    }
```

## To check secret code:

```
if (((MainForm) base.Owner) .Security.CheckKeys (this.UserName.Text, this.Company.Text, this.ProductKey.Text.Replace ( "-", "")))
         {
             MessageBox.Show ( "True");
             ((MainForm) base.Owner) .Security.WriteRegInfo (this.UserName.Text, this.Company.Text, this.ProductKey.Text);
             base.Close ();
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show ( "False");
         }
```

Please help me to make keygenerator. Thank you

Comment: OMG! Support for RC2 and DES both of which are now consider insecure and should not be used. And `goto` other than in early termination! Don't use hard coded IVs, use a Cryptographically secure random number generator and pre-pend the IV to the encrypted data. Also use a Cryptographically secure random number generator for the key.

Comment: simple program. To protect it so. The client had to ask that at least some protection.

Comment: It borders on criminal to use poor cryptography when secure cryptography is no more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Cryptographically secure random number generator for the key, see [RandomNumberGenerator Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.randomnumbergenerator(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The window for my program to how to make keygenerator just do not want to re-program my project

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
    using System.Security.Cryptography;
    public static string GenerateAPIKey()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] apiKey = new byte[32];
        rng.GetBytes(apiKey);
        string s = System.Convert.ToBase64String(apiKey);
        return s;
    }
```

Comment: Why convert to Base64, encryption and the keys are 8-bit data.

Comment: It made sense for my application to convert it. Is there any harm in it @zaph?

Comment: Just that it has to be converted back to data prior to use.

Comment: Not fully following you. But no need to convert it back in my case.

Comment: If you need a 32-byte key converting to Base64 will create a 44-byte string.

Comment: OK, I see, thanks. Maybe the code could look better but I wanted a long string in the end. No need to down vote though :)

Comment: The point of SO is not about what worked for the answerer but to provide good answers for the future. This question seems to be about generating an encryption key.